# Magnific-popup doesn't work at all

Tags: jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

i'm with some problems here. I've tried everything for days! I already look at other questions here to try to solve my problem, but i can't still make magnific-popup to work.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i searched google, the original documentation, stackoverflow questions, but my site just doesn't show the pop-up.

Here is the code i have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magnific-popup.css" />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function($){
        // Inline popups
            $('#inline-popups').magnificPopup({
                delegate: 'a',
                removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
                callbacks: {
                    beforeOpen: function() {
                        this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
                    }
                },
                midClick: true // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
            });
        }); 
        </script>

</head>
<body>

<h3>Magnific Popup CSS3-based animation effects</h3>
<div class="links">
  <h4>Text-based:</h4>
  <ul id="inline-popups">
    <li><a href="#test-popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">Zoom-out</a></li>
  </ul>

<!-- Popup itself -->
<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide">You may put any HTML here. This is dummy copy. It is not meant to be read. It has been placed here solely to demonstrate the look and feel of finished, typeset text. Only for show. He who searches for meaning here will be sorely disappointed.</div>


</body>
</html>
```

---

The JS and CSS file included in my project i made the download from this page: 
https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/tree/master/dist

---

I also added some extra code on my CSS file based on this stackoverflow question:
[I can't get magnific-popup animations to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371848/i-cant-get-magnific-popup-animations-to-work)

This is the CSS code i added:

```
html,body {margin:0; padding:10px; -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}

/* text-based popup styling */
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 25px;
  width:auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

/* 

====== Zoom-out effect ======

*/
.mfp-zoom-out.mfp-bg {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.mfp-zoom-out.mfp-bg.mfp-ready {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.mfp-zoom-out.mfp-bg.mfp-removing {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.mfp-zoom-out .mfp-content{
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
.mfp-zoom-out.mfp-ready .mfp-content {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.mfp-zoom-out.mfp-removing .mfp-content {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}


/* preview styles */
html {
  font-family: "Calibri", "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
a,
  a:visited {
    color: #1760BF;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: #c00;
  }
.links {
  ul {

  }
  li {
   margin-bottom: 5px; 
  }
}
h4 {
  margin: 24px 0 0 0;
}

.bottom-text {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-top: 2px solid #CCC;
  a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  }
  p {
   max-width: 650px; 
  }
}

/*
```

I really hope you guys can help me, because i don't know what else i can do to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle please? http://jsfiddle.net/ It's easier for us to find the problem with this..

Comment: i added the library and your css to the this [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r6CkaW9I9OAM8YktDjj8?p=preview)

Comment: I'm kind of new to jsfiddle, so i hope it´s correct. This is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/qsD25/ Please, notice that i used other external links, they are on the external resources panel, because the code is pretty extensive. Thanks

Comment: Does the example of David give you what you want?

Comment: The pop-up is working on the David example. But i can't make it work.. Doesn't matter what i do, even if i only put the pop-up plug-in in a clean webpage... This is the actual WebSite i'm orking on: http://testes-cmt.bl.ee/ There is the "zoom-ou" link, but no pop-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution to your problem is, you didn't download the correct file for your Magnific-popup script.

You just downloaded the complete gitHub Page, not the needed css/jquery file.

You need to download this file [jQuery](https://raw.github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js) and this [CSS](https://raw.github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css).

On gitHub pages you have to click the "raw" tab, to get the clean code you need for your projects.

Comment: I could made it work. Thanks! Finally! I'm about 3-4 days trying to solve this, and it was a very simple fix (i was pretty silly btw). WebSite with the plugin work, in case you wanna see http://testes-cmt.bl.ee