# jquery Magnific Popup won't work - js-newbie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

what am I doing wrong? this is the easiest variation from magnific popup, but I just can't get this running for hours. I'm a newbie to JS, but other things worked out pretty well?!

i used the JS-File from here https://raw.github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
from that stackoverflow post: [Magnific-popup doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438407/magnific-popup-doesnt-work-at-all)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#some-button, #some-button2 {padding:20px}
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 2000px;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Magnific Popup CSS */
.mfp-bg {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1042;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  background: #0b0b0b;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80); }

.mfp-wrap {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1043;
  position: fixed;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }

.mfp-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.mfp-container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.mfp-align-top .mfp-container:before {
  display: none; }

.mfp-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1045; }

.mfp-inline-holder .mfp-content, .mfp-ajax-holder .mfp-content {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: auto; }

.mfp-ajax-cur {
  cursor: progress; }

.mfp-zoom-out-cur, .mfp-zoom-out-cur .mfp-image-holder .mfp-close {
  cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
  cursor: zoom-out; }

.mfp-zoom {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
  cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
  cursor: zoom-in; }

.mfp-auto-cursor .mfp-content {
  cursor: auto; }

.mfp-close, .mfp-arrow, .mfp-preloader, .mfp-counter {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; }

.mfp-loading.mfp-figure {
  display: none; }

.mfp-hide {
  display: none !important; }

.mfp-preloader {
  color: #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -0.8em;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  z-index: 1044; }
  .mfp-preloader a {
    color: #CCC; }
    .mfp-preloader a:hover {
      color: #FFF; }

.mfp-s-ready .mfp-preloader {
  display: none; }

.mfp-s-error .mfp-content {
  display: none; }

button.mfp-close, button.mfp-arrow {
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1046;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none; }
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0; }

.mfp-close {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  padding: 0 0 18px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Baskerville, monospace; }
  .mfp-close:hover, .mfp-close:focus {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
  .mfp-close:active {
    top: 1px; }

.mfp-close-btn-in .mfp-close {
  color: #333; }

.mfp-image-holder .mfp-close, .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close {
  color: #FFF;
  right: -6px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 6px;
  width: 100%; }

.mfp-counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #CCC;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  white-space: nowrap; }

.mfp-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -55px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 110px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
  .mfp-arrow:active {
    margin-top: -54px; }
  .mfp-arrow:hover, .mfp-arrow:focus {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
  .mfp-arrow:before, .mfp-arrow:after, .mfp-arrow .mfp-b, .mfp-arrow .mfp-a {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    border: medium inset transparent; }
  .mfp-arrow:after, .mfp-arrow .mfp-a {
    border-top-width: 13px;
    border-bottom-width: 13px;
    top: 8px; }
  .mfp-arrow:before, .mfp-arrow .mfp-b {
    border-top-width: 21px;
    border-bottom-width: 21px;
    opacity: 0.7; }

.mfp-arrow-left {
  left: 0; }
  .mfp-arrow-left:after, .mfp-arrow-left .mfp-a {
    border-right: 17px solid #FFF;
    margin-left: 31px; }
  .mfp-arrow-left:before, .mfp-arrow-left .mfp-b {
    margin-left: 25px;
    border-right: 27px solid #3F3F3F; }

.mfp-arrow-right {
  right: 0; }
  .mfp-arrow-right:after, .mfp-arrow-right .mfp-a {
    border-left: 17px solid #FFF;
    margin-left: 39px; }
  .mfp-arrow-right:before, .mfp-arrow-right .mfp-b {
    border-left: 27px solid #3F3F3F; }

.mfp-iframe-holder {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px; }
  .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-content {
    line-height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px; }
  .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close {
    top: -40px; }

.mfp-iframe-scaler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%; }
  .mfp-iframe-scaler iframe {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #000; }

/* Main image in popup */
img.mfp-img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px 0 40px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

/* The shadow behind the image */
.mfp-figure {
  line-height: 0; }
  .mfp-figure:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #444; }
  .mfp-figure small {
    color: #BDBDBD;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px; }
  .mfp-figure figure {
    margin: 0; }

.mfp-bottom-bar {
  margin-top: -36px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: auto; }

.mfp-title {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #F3F3F3;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-right: 36px; }

.mfp-image-holder .mfp-content {
  max-width: 100%; }

.mfp-gallery .mfp-image-holder .mfp-figure {
  cursor: pointer; }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape), screen and (max-height: 300px) {
  /**
       * Remove all paddings around the image on small screen
       */
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-image-holder {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile img.mfp-img {
    padding: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-figure:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-figure small {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-bottom-bar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: auto;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; }
    .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-bottom-bar:empty {
      padding: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-counter {
    right: 5px;
    top: 3px; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-close {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0; }
 }

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  .mfp-arrow {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    transform: scale(0.75); }

  .mfp-arrow-left {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
    transform-origin: 0; }

  .mfp-arrow-right {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100%; }

  .mfp-container {
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px; }
 }

.mfp-ie7 .mfp-img {
  padding: 0; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-bottom-bar {
  width: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-container {
  padding: 0; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-content {
  padding-top: 44px; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-close {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script>
// Example with multiple objects
$('#some-button').magnificPopup({
    items: [
      {
        src: 'pic.jpg'
      },
      {
        src: 'http://vimeo.com/123123',
        type: 'iframe' // this overrides default type
      },
      {
        src: $('<div>Dynamically created element</div>'), // Dynamically created element
        type: 'inline'
      },
      {
        src: '<div>HTML string</div>',
        type: 'inline'
      },
      {
        src: '#my-popup', // CSS selector of an element on page that should be used as a popup
        type: 'inline'
      }
    ],
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    type: 'image' // this is default type
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="some-button">Popup</button>
<div id="my-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">Inline popup</div>

<!-- also tried to implement JScripts here -->
</body>
</html>
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: tried it on opera 28.0., firefox 37.0.1. on a win7 machine

Comment: You are trying to use jQuery before it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a function

```
$(function () {
$('#some-button').magnificPopup({
items: [
  {
    src: 'pic.jpg'
  },
  {
    src: 'http://vimeo.com/123123',
    type: 'iframe' // this overrides default type
  },
  {
    src: $('<div>Dynamically created element</div>'), // Dynamically created element
    type: 'inline'
  },
  {
    src: '<div>HTML string</div>',
    type: 'inline'
  },
  {
    src: '#my-popup', // CSS selector of an element on page that should be used as a popup
    type: 'inline'
  }
],
gallery: {
  enabled: true
},
type: 'image' // this is default type
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Karl-André Gagnon:

it worked like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script>
// Example with multiple objects
$(document).ready(function() {
 

$('#some-button').magnificPopup({
    items: [
      {
        src: 'pic.jpg'
      },
      {
        src: 'http://vimeo.com/123123',
        type: 'iframe' // this overrides default type
      },
      {
        src: $('<div>Dynamically created element</div>'), // Dynamically created element
        type: 'inline'
      },
      {
        src: '<div>HTML string</div>',
        type: 'inline'
      },
      {
        src: '#my-popup', // CSS selector of an element on page that should be used as a popup
        type: 'inline'
      }
    ],
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    type: 'image' // this is default type
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<button id="some-button">Popup</button>
<div id="my-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">Inline popup</div>

<!-- also tried to implement JScripts here -->
</body>
</html>
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#some-button, #some-button2 {padding:20px}
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 2000px;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Magnific Popup CSS */
.mfp-bg {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1042;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  background: #0b0b0b;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80); }

.mfp-wrap {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1043;
  position: fixed;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }

.mfp-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.mfp-container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.mfp-align-top .mfp-container:before {
  display: none; }

.mfp-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1045; }

.mfp-inline-holder .mfp-content, .mfp-ajax-holder .mfp-content {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: auto; }

.mfp-ajax-cur {
  cursor: progress; }

.mfp-zoom-out-cur, .mfp-zoom-out-cur .mfp-image-holder .mfp-close {
  cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
  cursor: zoom-out; }

.mfp-zoom {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
  cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
  cursor: zoom-in; }

.mfp-auto-cursor .mfp-content {
  cursor: auto; }

.mfp-close, .mfp-arrow, .mfp-preloader, .mfp-counter {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; }

.mfp-loading.mfp-figure {
  display: none; }

.mfp-hide {
  display: none !important; }

.mfp-preloader {
  color: #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -0.8em;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  z-index: 1044; }
  .mfp-preloader a {
    color: #CCC; }
    .mfp-preloader a:hover {
      color: #FFF; }

.mfp-s-ready .mfp-preloader {
  display: none; }

.mfp-s-error .mfp-content {
  display: none; }

button.mfp-close, button.mfp-arrow {
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1046;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none; }
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0; }

.mfp-close {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  padding: 0 0 18px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Baskerville, monospace; }
  .mfp-close:hover, .mfp-close:focus {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
  .mfp-close:active {
    top: 1px; }

.mfp-close-btn-in .mfp-close {
  color: #333; }

.mfp-image-holder .mfp-close, .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close {
  color: #FFF;
  right: -6px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 6px;
  width: 100%; }

.mfp-counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #CCC;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  white-space: nowrap; }

.mfp-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -55px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 110px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
  .mfp-arrow:active {
    margin-top: -54px; }
  .mfp-arrow:hover, .mfp-arrow:focus {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
  .mfp-arrow:before, .mfp-arrow:after, .mfp-arrow .mfp-b, .mfp-arrow .mfp-a {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    border: medium inset transparent; }
  .mfp-arrow:after, .mfp-arrow .mfp-a {
    border-top-width: 13px;
    border-bottom-width: 13px;
    top: 8px; }
  .mfp-arrow:before, .mfp-arrow .mfp-b {
    border-top-width: 21px;
    border-bottom-width: 21px;
    opacity: 0.7; }

.mfp-arrow-left {
  left: 0; }
  .mfp-arrow-left:after, .mfp-arrow-left .mfp-a {
    border-right: 17px solid #FFF;
    margin-left: 31px; }
  .mfp-arrow-left:before, .mfp-arrow-left .mfp-b {
    margin-left: 25px;
    border-right: 27px solid #3F3F3F; }

.mfp-arrow-right {
  right: 0; }
  .mfp-arrow-right:after, .mfp-arrow-right .mfp-a {
    border-left: 17px solid #FFF;
    margin-left: 39px; }
  .mfp-arrow-right:before, .mfp-arrow-right .mfp-b {
    border-left: 27px solid #3F3F3F; }

.mfp-iframe-holder {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px; }
  .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-content {
    line-height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px; }
  .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close {
    top: -40px; }

.mfp-iframe-scaler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%; }
  .mfp-iframe-scaler iframe {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #000; }

/* Main image in popup */
img.mfp-img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px 0 40px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

/* The shadow behind the image */
.mfp-figure {
  line-height: 0; }
  .mfp-figure:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #444; }
  .mfp-figure small {
    color: #BDBDBD;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px; }
  .mfp-figure figure {
    margin: 0; }

.mfp-bottom-bar {
  margin-top: -36px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: auto; }

.mfp-title {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #F3F3F3;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-right: 36px; }

.mfp-image-holder .mfp-content {
  max-width: 100%; }

.mfp-gallery .mfp-image-holder .mfp-figure {
  cursor: pointer; }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape), screen and (max-height: 300px) {
  /**
       * Remove all paddings around the image on small screen
       */
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-image-holder {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile img.mfp-img {
    padding: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-figure:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-figure small {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-bottom-bar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: auto;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; }
    .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-bottom-bar:empty {
      padding: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-counter {
    right: 5px;
    top: 3px; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-close {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0; }
 }

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  .mfp-arrow {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    transform: scale(0.75); }

  .mfp-arrow-left {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
    transform-origin: 0; }

  .mfp-arrow-right {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100%; }

  .mfp-container {
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px; }
 }

.mfp-ie7 .mfp-img {
  padding: 0; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-bottom-bar {
  width: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-container {
  padding: 0; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-content {
  padding-top: 44px; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-close {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script>
// Example with multiple objects
$('#some-button').magnificPopup({
    items: [
      {
        src: 'pic.jpg'
      },
      {
        src: 'http://vimeo.com/123123',
        type: 'iframe' // this overrides default type
      },
      {
        src: $('<div>Dynamically created element</div>'), // Dynamically created element
        type: 'inline'
      },
      {
        src: '<div>HTML string</div>',
        type: 'inline'
      },
      {
        src: '#my-popup', // CSS selector of an element on page that should be used as a popup
        type: 'inline'
      }
    ],
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    type: 'image' // this is default type
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="some-button">Popup</button>
<div id="my-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">Inline popup</div>

<!-- also tried to implement JScripts here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here's correct, I just want to make it clear.

You are trying to act on an element that has not loaded. Both Jquery and the actual DOM elements you're manipulating won't have loaded by the time your 3rd party JS is executed.

Without JQuery, your included script is gibberish to the browser and unless the DOM is ready, the JS will simply return an error. 
Include your Jquery before the 3rd party plugin.

Do this by either including your script in an external file at the bottom AFTER the Jquery include, or shift Jquery up above the include. Then wrap your actual function in a 'onready' function:

As mvargos points out, you can wrap the JS in a

```
$(function(){}).
```

This is JQuery short hand for

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Document.ready means only run after the DOM has loaded and all your elements actually exist for the JS to act on.

[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page) SO question to know more.

Comment: Ah too slow. Glad you got it sorted though :)